# Swift Type subscripts

Tags: swift, xcode, types, subscript

In the Apple Language Guide for Swift 5.1 there is an example of Type Subscripts.

```
enum Planet: Int {
case mercury = 1, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune
static subscript(n: Int) -> Planet {
    return Planet(rawValue: n)!
}
}
let mars = Planet[4]
print(mars)
```

When I try to run it in a playground I get a compiler error:

Subscript cannot be marked 'static'

Is this a new feature specific to Swift 5.1?

My Xcode is 10.2.1 not 11 so I'm guessing that it is.

I also tried an online playground supposed to be compatible with Swift 5 but also got errors.  http://online.swiftplayground.run/

Answer (score 1):

[**`static` and `class` subscripts**](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0254-static-subscripts.md) are a new feature of Swift 5.1 as described in the Swift Evolution document [SE-0254](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0254-static-subscripts.md).

[The Swift 5.1 Programming Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Subscripts.html) describes this feature thusly:

> **Type Subscripts**
>
> Instance subscripts, as described above, are subscripts that you call
>   on an instance of a particular type. You can also define subscripts
>   that are called on the type itself. This kind of subscript is called a
>   *type subscript*. You indicate a type subscript by writing the `static`
>   keyword before the `subscript` keyword. Classes can use the `class`
>   keyword instead, to allow subclasses to override the superclass’s
>   implementation of that subscript.